# Add integers if value =! "X"

Tags: java, random

I have to figure out how to add integers and display in the console `System.out.println();` if the value of the random number is not `1,3,5`.
For example, if I random `3,3,5,6,1` (There will never be more than 5 random numbers) then I need to print a message and the sum of `6` and `1`. If the next random is `2,2,5,6,6,` then I need the message and the sum of `2+2+6+6`.

Any thoughts on how to accomplish this?

Using this to random the number:

```
Random rand = new Random();
int a = (int) (6 * rand.nextDouble() + 1);
```

Comment: For starters, if you want a random integer, just use `nextInt(n)`, but if you're asking us how to use `if` in Java, you need to go read the tutorials.

Comment: Something to get you started create a variable called sum and set it to zero. Create a for loop from i =0 to i =5 and call the two lines you have up in your question.  check if a is not equal to 1 3 or 5 then sum+= a.  After the for loop display and reset sum to 0.

Comment: how come you want to exclude 1 but then sum it with 6 in the first case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you only want to sum up even numbers (which i am assuming given your context), use a loop and modulo

```
int[] numbers = { 2, 2, 5, 6, 6 };

int sum = 0;
for (int number : numbers) {
    if(number % 2 == 0) {
        sum += number;
    }
}
```

if it is your goal to exclude a dynamic range of numbers when building the sum of an array of integers

```
int[] numbers = { 2, 2, 5, 6, 6 };
int[] excluded = { 1, 3, 5 };

int sum = 0;
for (int number : numbers) {

    if(Arrays.binarySearch(excluded, number) < 0) {
        sum += number;
    }
}
```

and if you want a highly extensible solution (or impress your teacher) do something like

```
interface Predicate<T> {
    boolean evaluate(T value);
}

public int sum(int[] numbers, Predicate<Integer> predicate) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int number : numbers) {
        if (predicate.evaluate(number)) {
            sum += number;
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

and then call

```
int[] numbers = { 2, 2, 5, 6, 6 };

int sum = sum(numbers, new Predicate<Integer>() {
    @Override
    public boolean evaluate(Integer value) {
        return !(value == 1 || value == 3 || value == 5);
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
if(!(a==1||a==3||a==5)){
    sum+=a;
}
```

This checks to see whether the value of `a` is equal to 1, 3, or 5, and if it is not, it adds `a` to the sum.

Also, it looks like you will never have numbers greater than 6; in this case, you can just check to see whether the number is even or odd using the modulus (remainder) operator. You can then just say:

```
if(a%2!=1){ //if the remainder when a is divided by 2 is not 1
            // - i.e. if a is not odd
    sum+=a;
}
```

Comment: One could speculate that the question is asking you to filter out odd numbers, but it would be precise to only check for 1, 3, and 5 since the question explicitly says to exclude them and nothing else. You'd be making assumptions about the domain which is not specified.

Comment: @MxyL The code snippet he posted will only give integers in the range 1 - 6.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson No, actually, it isn't. In Java, `=` is the assignment operator, and so `!a%2 = 0` won't even compile. You would have to use `==` or `!=`.

Comment: `!a%2 == 0` is the proper way to test for even or odd numbers

Comment: @JarrodRoberson How exactly is that different from `a%2!=0`?

Comment: @JarrodRoberson Well, yes. I know that. I want the condition to be true if the number is even.